# Spring permitAll() and ignorning() doesn't work

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security

I'm trying to configure Spring-Boot 2 application with in-memory authorization and it drive me crazy...

I need to secure all resources except `/news`.

I have created this configuration beans following the Spring's docs but Spring Security isn't permit GET method on `/news`:

```
@Slf4j
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class ApplicationAuthentication extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

@Override
public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
    web
            .ignoring()
            .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET,"/news");
}

@Override
protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth)
        throws Exception {
    auth
            .inMemoryAuthentication()
            .withUser("user")
            .password("password")
            .roles("USER")
            .and()
            .withUser("admin")
            .password("admin")
            .roles("USER", "ADMIN");
}

@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET,"/news")
            .permitAll()
            .anyRequest()
            .authenticated()
            .and()
            .httpBasic();
}
```

}

I'm using spring-boot 2.0.4.RELEASE,

Can someone help me?

Comment: What is the full name of class `HttpMethod`? What repsonse do you get?

Comment: Do you use a base-route like `/api/news`?

Comment: I'm really confused... I tried it with your setup and it worked as expected. `POST` to `/news` resulted in `401 unauthorized` and `GET` to `/news` resulted in `200`.

Comment: @git-flo It doesn't work for me...

Comment: Can you add your complete setup, including the news controller class?